# Change Position of inline popup

Tags: oracle-apex

I'm trying to use a single inline popup region with callout for a number of textfields.

Background: the inline popup consists of 5x5 buttons labeled "A1" to "E5" for risk assessment. Clicking a button should set the previously clicked textbox to "A1", "A2" and so on accordingly.

This all works fine, but I can't get the inline popup with callout to open at the right position (next to the textfield).

I can set the Custom Attribute to "data-parent-element="#TextfieldName"" once, and that works, but I want to dynamically change that.

I tried using a page item instead (data-parent-element= &P1_TEXTFIELDNAME.) and change that via a "Set Value"-Action. Still no "dynamic" behavior.
I tried changing the attribute "data-parent-element" via javascript and while inspecting the page shows that the attribute has changed, the behavior/position hasn't.

Any idea or advice how I can change the position of the inline popup at runtime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I stumbled upon the same issue and managed to find a solution that worked for me:

1.) Give the buttons a unique ID and a common class. 
2.) Add a dynamic action that should be fired by a click on any element with the common class. 
3.) Add a True action "Open Region", indicating your Inline Popup region. 
4.) Add another True action "Execute JavaScript Code" with the content below. The ID of the Inline Popup is "myPopup" in this case. Please note that also the data-parent-element attribute needs to be populated with a valid ID, although it will not be used.

```
    var parent = document.getElementById("myPopup").parentElement;
    var origin = document.getElementById(event.target.id).getBoundingClientRect();

    parent.style.left = origin.left +  "px";
    parent.style.top = origin.bottom + "px";
```

Comment: Works like a charm.
Thank you very much.